# Как лучше хранить данные в БД?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, хранение-данных

Стоит задача создать магазин с разными предметами. Я решил каждому предмету давать уникальный ID и если человек купил что либо то записывать в таблицу информацию:

```
|---------|----|
| Человек | ID |
|---------|----|
```

Человек - ID это будет уникальным ключом, но в магазине будет около 500 предметов и выходит если у человека будет все куплено то только для него одного будет выделяться 500 строк. Можно ли это реализовать как то лучше?

Comment: С точки зрения реляционной БД это совершенно правильный подход. Как то пересматривать такую структуру возможно потребуется для повышения производительности, но сказать что с ней можно сделать без знания всех задач решаемых системой невозможно

Comment: Если у вас будет 10 000 человек купивших по все 500 предметов .. то можно будет только порадоваться, и тогда уже думать про оптимизации.

Comment: Другими словами у вас стоит вопрос нормализации БД. Можете почитать тут https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/283878/description-of-the-database-normalization-basics  или погуглить еще.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если в общем, то верная логика. То, что будет 500 записей, если покупатель купил все 500 предметов, то этому можно только радоваться))) MySQL рассчитана на нагрузки в десятки и сотни миллионов строк на таблицу.

Другое дело, что на этапе проектирования желательно заранее предусмотреть тот факт, что у продукта может быть несколько артикулов. Лучше используйте SKU_ID для единицы товара (его используем также и в таблице заказов), а за вывод товарной карточки пусть отвечает PRODUCT_ID (который может иметь несколько SKU_ID). Это актуально для товаров с большим набором артикулов для одной и той же позиции (например, косметика - разные объемы, цветовые гаммы, одежда - разные размеры, цвета, электроника - разные цвета, комплектации).